# How to set class name placeholder in LESS

Tags: html, css, less

So I have a question - is it possible somehow set class name placeholder variable to use it in LESS. For example, I have some `div` with class and number variable:

```
<div class="width-10"></div>
<div class="width-13"></div>
<div class="width-20"></div>
<div class="width-25"></div>
<div class="width-48"></div>
```

In less I want something some this:

```
.width-@placeholder {
    width: @placeholder;
}
```

I resolve this problem as:

```
.setWidth(100);

.setWidth(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    &.width-@{i} {
      width: (@i * 1%);
    }
    .setWidth(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

But I thought it should be simpler then creating `"for each"`

Comment: Well, in general there's nothing more simple than `for each` (of any kind) because it cover *most of* uuse-case. It's not so difficult to imagine some `.width-@{from 1 to 100}` special construction but it's never worth burdening a language with too specific and thus very limited constructions (at least Less which is supposed to be as minimalistic as possible).

Comment: To simplify your recursion a bit, you could count downward instead of upward, and remove the `i` variable.

Comment: Or just use any of `loop` helper mixins. [For example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%40import%20%5C%22https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fseven-phases-max%2Fless.curious%2Fmaster%2Fsrc%2Ffor.less%5C%22%3B%5Cn%5Cn.for(10)%3B%20.-each(%40i)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.width-%40%7Bi%7D%20%7Bwidth%3A%20%40i%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D)

Comment: And it's assumed you can move the repetitive code to a reusable mixin. [Example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%2F%2F%20reusable%20stuff%3A%5Cn.1-10(%40style)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.-%3B%20.-(%40i%3A%2010)%20when%20(%40i%20%3E%200)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.-(%40i%20-%201)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%40style()%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20usage%3A%5Cn.1-10(%7B%5Cn%20%20.width-%40%7Bi%7D%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20%40i%20*%201%25%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%5Cn%20%20foo-%40%7Bi%7D%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20%40i%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D)%3B%22%7D).

Comment: thanks guys for your comments. Maybe you're right. BTW, is there simpler solution in sass?

Comment: Off topic, but I kinda miss a `px` in the sources.